# Is there any tool available to design and edit tables of SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-design, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

Are there any tools available to design and edit tables in a SQL Server CE 4.0 database?

I am using Visual Studio 2012, I can find the tables and its columns and properties etc. But seems I can't edit table's column properties.

Any standalone third party tools and or plugins any plugin in Visual Studio 2012/2012 for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the [SQL Server Compact Toolbox extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1?SRC=VSIDE)?

Add it to Visual Studio with the `Tools\Extensions and Updates` menu, then search the `Online` node.

[image]

> SQL Server Compact 3.5 and 4.0 Toolbox add-in for Visual Studio. This
>   add-in adds several features to help your SQL Server Compact
>   development efforts: Scripting of tables and data, import from SQL
>   Server and CSV files